# How do I retrieve a list of DocuSign shared templates

Tags: docusignapi

I have 2 shared templates in my DocuSign account.   I want to retrieve a list of shared templates.  I'm making the below ajax call.

I'm receiving a 200 status call so the call is successful but DocuSign is returning HTML not JSON.

```
var DSTemplateURL = localStorage.getItem("ls_DSurl") + "/v2/accounts/" + localStorage.getItem("ls_DS_accountid") + "/templates?";
var DSData = 'folder=Shared Templates';

request = $.ajax({
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('ls_DSaccess_token') },
    type: 'GET',
    url: DSTemplateURL,
    data: DSData,
    //dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: I was using the wrong URL.  Here is the wrong ajax code:

Comment: I was using {base uri}/v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates instead of {base uri}/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates.  The above code works when using the correct URL.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the [user_filter](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/list/) query string parameter.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates?user_filter=shared_with_me
```

Here are the possible values for the user_filter parameter.

- **owned_by_me**: only shows templates the user owns.
- **shared_with_me**: only shows templates that are shared with the user.
- **all**: shows all templates owned or shared with the user.

Change your code as follows

```
var DSTemplateURL = localStorage.getItem("ls_DSurl") + "/v2/accounts/" + localStorage.getItem("ls_DS_accountid") + "/templates?user_filter=shared_with_me";

request = $.ajax({
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +   localStorage.getItem('ls_DSaccess_token') },
  type: 'GET',
  url: DSTemplateURL,
  //dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json",
  cache: false
});
```